# String Utilities in C#

Tags: c#, string

I'm learning about string utilities in C#, and I have a method that replaces parts of a string.

Using the replace method I need to get an output such as

"Old file name: file00"

"New file name: file01"

Depending on what the user wants to change it to.

I am looking for help on making the method (`NextImageName`) replace only the digits, but not the file name.

```
class BuildingBlock
{
    public static string ReplaceOnce(string word, string characters, int position)
    {
        word = word.Remove(position, characters.Length);
        word = word.Insert(position, characters);
        return word;
    }

    public static string GetLastName(string name)
    {
        string result = "";
        int posn = name.LastIndexOf(' ');
        if (posn >= 0) result = name.Substring(posn + 1);
        return result;
    }

    public static string NextImageName(string filename, int newNumber)
    {
        if (newNumber > 9)
        {
            return ReplaceOnce(filename, newNumber, (filename.Length - 2))
        }
        if (newNumber < 10)
        {

        }
        if (newNumber == 0)
        {

        }
    }
```

The other "if" statements are empty for now until I find out how to do the first one.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.  The `ReplaceOnce` method is changing only the last two characters of `filename`.  What do you want to do differently?

Comment: ReplaceOne expects a string as second parameter, you pass an integer, this code will never compile as is

Comment: Please give some examples of what you want to accomplish, that makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: You could replace the contents of `GetLastName()` with this `return name.Split(' ').Last();`

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be to use [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Ideally you would separate "file" from "00" in "file00".  Then take "00", convert it to an `Int32` (using `Int32.Parse()`) and then rebuild your string with `String.Format()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string NextImageName(string filename, int newNumber)
{
    string oldnumber = "";
    foreach (var item in filename.ToCharArray().Reverse())
        if (char.IsDigit(item))
            oldnumber = item + oldnumber ;
        else
            break;

    return filename.Replace(oldnumber ,newNumber.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string NextImageName(string filename, int newNumber)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (char c in filename)  // get index of first number
    {
        if (char.IsNumber(c))
            break;
        else
            i++;
    }

    string s = filename.Substring(0,i);  // remove original number
    s = s + newNumber.ToString();        // add new number

    return s;

}
```